# How can I switch the positive line with 5V in a 12V circuit?

Tags: transistors, led-strip

I have a 12V LED. I have a sensor. I am trying to switch the 12V wire that feeds the LED with the 5V current coming out of the sensor, but I have not been successful.

I can switch the ground line, but the LEDs are unstable. How can I switch the positive line without using a relay?

---

I am getting 5V output from ttp223 sensor, I am trying to switch power wire of ws2811 led with it

Comment: Use the PS with shutdown feature.

Comment: Please show the schematic of the unstable low-side switch. Please also link the data sheet for the LED. Please also link the data sheet of the low-side (ground) switching device.

Comment: You need a level shifter and a PNP Bipolar or P-channel MOSFET. Google high-side switch.

Comment: What exactly does *"the LEDs are unstable"* mean?? (Sounds like you have some other problem that you cannot explain to us and that you've made your own decision about using a high-side switch instead as the "fix" to this earlier issue. I'd like to know more about the earlier issue.)

Answer (score 2):

Without showing us what circuit you used to do the switching, it's impossible to say why it didn't work, but switching on the negative side should be perfectly fine.

Anyway, as requested, here's a design which will switch the *positive* (+12V) supply of the LEDs using a P-channel MOSFET:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI35c6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

M1 produces +12V or 0V at the gate of M2, under control of a 0V or 5V signal from the sensor. This will ensure that M2 is *completely* off or on.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I have ordered the products, when they arrive, I will test them and get back to you.

Comment: Hello teacher. I built the circuit. I connected the ws2811 to its driver. But contrary to what we want, the leds are constantly on. They turn off when I touch the sensor. And they do not go out completely, the current is on them even if it is small. Can you think of another solution? I can't switch from ground line, because they get power from data. So I need to switch over 12v.

Comment: @ismailorhan Time for some testing. Place a voltmeter between ground and the TTP223 output. Tell me what it reads when the sensor is touched/not touched. Also, what happens to the LED on the sensor module itself?

Comment: There is a voltage of 5V between the ground and the output of the sensor, sir.5V when I touch the sensor, 0V when I don't. The LED on the module lights up red when I touch it.

Comment: What voltages do you get between ground and the gate of M2?

Comment: I went to a solution like this, sir. I closed the B leg of the TTP223. It's what I want now. But when I power the circuit, the led on the sensor lights up Continually. Does the continuous current in the sensor have any effect on its life? Will it do any harm?

Comment: @ismailorhan I don't know what "closed the B leg means". I don't think it will do any harm, but it's not right. Can you update your question with the current schematic, including part numbers?

Comment: I would appreciate if you could help me in your free time, sir.